# Implementing a service in background on iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have a custom framework which the client app can consume. I want the framework API's to run even when the application enters the background. How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your app is doing after entering the background.

Perhaps you are looking for UIBackgroundTask. You can take a look at the method [beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) of UIApplication.

> This method lets your app continue to run for a period of time after it transitions to the background. You should call this method at times where leaving a task unfinished might be detrimental to your app’s user experience. For example, your app could call this method to ensure that had enough time to transfer an important file to a remote server or at least attempt to make the transfer and note any errors. You should not use this method simply to keep your app running after it moves to the background.

Answer (score 0):

Background execution on iOS is a very advanced topic.

Without any details, all I can do is forward you to the official Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1).

This explains ALL possible modes that allow your app to run in background.